# How do you code php to check for empties and if not then run the sql query?

Tags: php, sql

This is what I have and it's not working. I need to check if the fields in Your_Location.php is empty. If it is, throw an error. If not; run the query as follow. It would work if I throw in //if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sqlinsert))

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    include 'dbConfig.php';
    include 'Your_Location.php';

    $childfirst = $_POST['element_1'];
    $childlast = $_POST['element_2'];
    $childdobyear = $_POST['element_3_3'];
    $childdobmon = $_POST['element_3_1'];
    $childdobday = $_POST['element_3_2'];
    $childbaptize = $_POST['element_4'];
    $childrelationship = $_POST['inputrelation'];
    $childdob = "$childdobyear-$childdobmon-$childdobday";



    $sqlinsert="INSERT INTO memchild (ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Baptize, Relationship)
    VALUES
    ('$getid2','$childfirst','$childlast','$childdob','$childbaptize','$childrelationship')";



    //Build arrays of fields

    $required = array('element_1', 'element_2', 'element_3_3', 'element_3_2', 'element_3_1', 'elelment_4', 'inputrelation');

    //Loop to check for empties
    $error = false;

    foreach($required as $fields) {
        if(empty($_POST[$fields])){
            $error = true;
        }
    }

    if($error){
    Sleep(3)
    ?>  
    <script>
      document.getElementById('li_9').innerHTML = '* $childfirst Make sure the fields are not empty.';
    </script>
    <?php
    exit();
    }Else{
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlinsert)
    ?>  
    <script>
      document.getElementById('li_9').innerHTML = '$childfirst $childlast has been added.';
    </script>
    <?php
    sleep(3);
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This works, but I need to check and see if fields are empty.

<?php

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sqlinsert))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
 }
Else
{
 echo "1 record added";
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
?>

Comment: What does this have to do with `Java`? Did you perhaps mean `JavaScript`, which is an entirely different language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to check if the keys actually exist.

```
$childfirst = isset($_POST['element_1'])? $_POST['element_1'] : null;
```

secondly, you can check what field is not filled in:

```
$errorMessage = '';
foreach($required as $key) {
    if(empty($_POST[$key])){
        $error = true;
        // break; // Uncomment if you want to exit the loop if one field is not set
       // $errorMessage .= $key . ' is not filled in'; // Uncomment if you want to add message for every missing key
    }
}
```

for your scripts, you are trying to combine PHP value with javascript, you need to actually echo or print the value like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('li_9').innerHTML += "* <?php echo $childfirst;?> Make sure the fields are not empty.";
</script>
```

and also for the second one

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('li_9').innerHTML += "<?php echo $childFirst . ' ' . $childLast;?> has been added.";
</script>
```

Comment: works, but it does not break the loop if I uncomment break.

Comment: @JohnHang it will exit the loop and continue to execute the lines after the foreach() {}. if you want to stop executing code, replace the break; with exit();

Answer (score 0):

Hey your error is you passing string values to check  and its not empty already

change this line

```
$required = array('element_1', 'element_2', 'element_3_3', 'element_3_2', 'element_3_1', 'elelment_4', 'inputrelation');
```

to

```
$required = array("$element_1", "$element_2");
```

Add the other elements too

And change this too

```
foreach($required as $fields) {
    if(empty($fields)){
        $error = true;
    }
}
```

Hope it works for You